# Did Amasa Ransom from Litchfield (Connecticut) serve as sea captain during American Revolution?

Tags: 18th-century, connecticut, american-revolution

Amasa Ransom from Litchfield (Connecticut) is reported to have been a sea captain.

Could he have served with the American forces early in the revolution ( 1775- 1776)?

He was married to Abigail Mather.

Their son Judah went on to become a early captain on the Great lakes.

Where can I find records showing this family's maritime history?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] which explains some of the features of this site.  In particular, please do not be offended by some edits that I have performed on your question that may help your question to attract potential answerers.

Comment: I assume that you have seen this Find A Grave link: http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=102892810 - although I just realised that this Amasa Ransom was born too late to be the one you are asking about.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  Can you tell us the source of the information in your question, so we can see what you have already looked at?  Do you have any other details that would help someone place this family on a timeline?